# alternative replaceWith() jquery without losing second element

Tags: jquery, replacewith

example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#exp1").replaceWith($("#exp2"));
});
</script>


<div class="exp1">example 1</div>
<div class="exp2">example 2</div>
```

when I use that code, I lost exp2 ( mean example 2 not showing ), only display example 1 which has been replace with example 2..
how do I not lose and just replace exp1 with exp2, and displays the result as below

```
<div class="exp2">example 2</div>
<div class="exp2">example 2</div>
```

please help me .. thanks

Comment: `$(".exp1").replaceWith(".exp2");` use this. http://jsfiddle.net/buGH8/1/

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense: there aren't any elements that match the selectors `#exp1` or `exp2`.

Comment: please see my latest edits..

Comment: Still won't replicate the problem: the selectors match ids but the elements have classes.

Comment: yes Juhana that was my mistake..I have changed it and now it has changed to classes..I have get the answer from @Satpal..thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You should [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) element then use the [`replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method. Also you need to use [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".exp1").replaceWith($(".exp2").clone());
});
```

[**Demo on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VJ8S/)

Comment: You know perfectly well why the answer was first downvoted. Unfortunately the ninja-edits don't leave a mark in the answer history, but the answer kept bouncing between using ids and classes.

Comment: @Juhana But i wonder why did guys downvote the first post, posted by the user balach..? That is perfectly alright.. Isn't..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Can't know for sure, but `[0].outerHTML` is pretty sketchy and isn't exactly the same as `.clone()`.